# sql query giving weird results

Tags: mysql, database

why is this query giving weird results..

```
SELECT max(greatest(home_team_total,away_team_total)) AS max_team_score, id 
FROM `match`
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

while

```
SELECT greatest(home_team_total,away_team_total) AS max_team_score, id 
FROM `match`
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
ORDER BY max_team_score DESC
LIMIT 1
```

gives correct result..

**The max value is correct only in both cases but id of match is wrong in first case..**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're including the `id` field in the SELECT clause. Which id do you want? I get that you might want the one associated with the max row, but there could be multiple ones, and what if you were also returning `min(greatest(home_team_total,away_team_total))`?

The second query is the one you want for this problem.

*Editing to make it a little clearer:*

Your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT max(greatest(home_team_total,away_team_total)) AS max_team_score, ANY(id)
FROM `match`
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

It says: *"The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate."*

Comment: Well as I mentioned in question I want id of match table's row corresponding to the maximum of greatest of scores..and I will never need minmum..and there are not multiple rows for this time..and even if there are more than one, it can return any one's I only need it for stats..

Comment: I get that's what you want, but pretend I'm playing the part of the server. It doesn't know the answers to these questions.

Comment: the whole question is why is first query wrong...technically??

Comment: Because if I don't get the reason, I'll be in trouble some other day with similar problem..

Comment: Because `id` is neither in a GROUP BY clause or in an aggregate. It will return one, but it makes no guarantee which one.

Comment: SO if I need to run it through first one..I'll need to have a GROUP BY max_team_score??

Comment: No. You'd need to use an analytic function like FIRST_VALUE(), which isn't available in MySQL. So use the second query. There are some tricks you can do to pretend to make it work, but it's way more advanced and non-intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

If you do want the first query to work, you have to change it to something like the following:

SELECT greatest(home_team_total,away_team_total) AS max_team_score, id 
FROM `match`
WHERE greatest(home_team_total,away_team_total) =
(
SELECT max(greatest(home_team_total,away_team_total)) FROM `match`
)

Note that you can have more than one row in the result, so I would prefer this solution to the "LIMIT 1" alternative.

Comment: first of all..Y??? and second whats the problem if there are more than one results..anyway I only want one result..let it be of any one..

Comment: Think about a case when there's a race and it ends in a tie. You would have the winners sharing the spot on the podium rather than giving the prize to only one of the winners.

However, if your solution works with only displaying one of the rows, then you can use the query posted earlier or add-on a LIMIT 1 to this query (or use the first result and discard the remaining results through your application).